# Managed Bootstrapper Application Update DetectUpdateBegin

Tags: wix

I am using the WiX Source\Setup\WixBA as a starting point for a custom managed bootstrapper application.

I am trying to wrap my head around how the `UpdateCommand` works but I don't even see the `DetectUpdateBegin` method get fired.

I see the `DetectComplete` method get fired but that just goes straight to setting `this.State = UpdateState.Current` without checking for updates.

What am I missing?

Ultimately I am trying to get the Bootstrapper to query a remote server and download an updated version of itself instead of having to distribute the updated bootstrapper.exe to the clients again.

```
=====UpdateViewModel=====

public UpdateViewModel(RootViewModel root)
{
    this.root = root;
    CustomBA.Model.Bootstrapper.DetectUpdateBegin += DetectUpdateBegin;
    CustomBA.Model.Bootstrapper.DetectComplete += DetectComplete;

    this.State = UpdateState.Initializing;

    this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    this.worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
}

private void DetectUpdateBegin(object sender, Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.DetectUpdateBeginEventArgs e)
{
    CustomBA.Model.LogMessage("[DEBUG-Update] DetectUpdateBegin: " + e.UpdateLocation);
    this.State = UpdateState.Checking;
    this.worker.RunWorkerAsync(e.UpdateLocation);
}

private void DetectComplete(object sender, Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    CustomBA.Model.LogMessage("[DEBUG-Update] DetectComplete: ");
    // If we never started checking, assume we're up to date.
    if (UpdateState.Initializing == this.State)
    {
        this.State = UpdateState.Current;
    }
}

=========================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DetectUpdateBegin` method is not fired unless you have the `Update` tag defined in your `Bundle.wxs`.

Adding the following resolved the issue:

`<Update Location="http://myserver/MyApp/updatefeed.xml"/>`